# App State: undefined and endless waiting tests

Tags: testing, react-native, e2e-testing, detox

Somehow when running our e2e detox tests we always wait for some synchronization to finish (If we disable it and wait manually it works).

I tried removing all animation but somehow there is still something running.

The log shows the following:

`detox info Sync App State: undefined
detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":21}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":21,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"App State","info":{"elements":["<UIViewController: 0x7fdc1351bf50>"],"appState":"Waiting for window's root view controller's view to appear."}},{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x112beadc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x112bec300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":21}}
detox verb ws
detox info Sync App State: undefined
detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":22}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":22,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"App State","info":{"elements":["<UIViewController: 0x7fdc1351bf50>"],"appState":"Waiting for window's root view controller's view to appear."}},{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x112beadc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x112bec300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":22}}`

Any help where this issue is coming from highly appreciated

[Update 2018/04/18]:

Just to clarify:

The render function of my app component is like that:

```
render() {
  const {
    isOnboardingVisible,
  } = this.props;

  if (isOnboardingVisible) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Onboarding onPressButton={this.props.onOnboardingViewed} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return  <LoginScreen statusBarHidden {!!this.props.notification} />;
};
```

The test navigates from the onboarding to the login screen by changing the `isOnboardingVisible` prop and gets stuck in the login screen waiting for an element to be visible (it's clearly visible on the screen).

If I remove the onboarding screen and directly start the test on the login screen the test works.

Here is our AppDelegate.m like requested in the comments:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <BugsnagReactNative/BugsnagReactNative.h>
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#import <react-native-branch/RNBranch.h>
#import "OneSignalConfig.h"
#import <React/RCTPushNotificationManager.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize oneSignal = _oneSignal;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
  NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = [plistDict objectForKey:@"CLIENT_ID"];

  #ifdef FREEWORK_DEBUG
    [RNBranch useTestInstance];
  #endif

  #ifdef FREEWORK_EDGE
    [RNBranch useTestInstance];
  #endif

  #ifdef FREEWORK_STAGING
    [RNBranch useTestInstance];
  #endif
  [RNBranch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions isReferrable:YES];
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

#ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
    jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Freework"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  OneSignalConfig* config = [[OneSignalConfig alloc] init];

  self.oneSignal = [[RCTOneSignal alloc] initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                                         appId: [config getOneSignalAppId]
                                         settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: @false}];

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [BugsnagReactNative start];
  [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  BOOL handled = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                            annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  return handled;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

  if (![RNBranch.branch application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) {
    if ([LinkedinSwiftHelper shouldHandleUrl:url]) {
      return [LinkedinSwiftHelper application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    } else if ([[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                            annotation:annotation]) {
      return YES;
    } else if( [url.absoluteString rangeOfString: @"fb" ].location != NSNotFound ) {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    } else {
    }
  }

  return YES;
}

// Respond to Universal Links
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler {
  return [RNBranch continueUserActivity:userActivity];
} // Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

@end
```

Comment: Something is ill-defined in your app—I'd guess in how it is being started in the native part.

Comment: You need to post more info on how your UI is set up in the app delegate.

Comment: @LeoNatan Hi Leo. Thanks a lot for your help. I updated the description with more information.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Could you please upload a test project where this reproduces? I want to debug in native.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, but it only happens whenI use 'tap' in detox.  Using tap makes reloadReactNative never complete with message 'Waiting for window's root view controller's view to appear.'  More details here: https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/691